# SharePoint Workflow to Send email triggering based on condition in a list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365, designer-workflow

Desk in SharePoint Online site. Basically i have created a Workflow which sends alert mail with list values, now i have to send email trigger based on help-desk priority like high priority ticket is raised secondary (alert) mail should trigger in 15 minutes, if its low priority secondary mail should trigger in 2 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write If condition in workflow

Remember to edit WF Settings and check Start WF when an item is added or Changed according to the requirement

If Priority is equal to High,
Pause for duration,
Send email

If Priority is Low,
Pause for duration,
Send email

[image: WF]

Comment: hi sir kan kan, thanks for your answer .  am a pure c#  developer.so am new to SPD Workflow, can u explain more details or share screen pic of workflow it will be more helpful for me.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check it.

Comment: thank u so much sri khan

Comment: its working perfectly in my environment.